# Model not converge (loss not decrease)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I have train dataset with shape of (108885, 128):

```
>print(features)
array([[155,  22, 159, ..., 117, 134, 255],
       [149,  17, 160, ..., 125,  84, 255],
       [149,  21, 157, ...,  98,  49, 255],
       ...,
       [159,  35, 136, ...,   3,   0, 255],
       [150,  28, 111, ...,   0,   0, 255],
       [149,  30, 107, ...,   0,   0, 255]], dtype=uint8)
```

Also I have one-hot encoded labels (5 classes) with shape of (108885, 5):

```
>print(one_hot_labels)
array([[0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

I'm trying to fit simple keras model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_shape=features[0].shape, activation="tanh"))
model.add(Dense(5, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True), loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(features, one_hot_labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.33)
```

I have tried a lot of different activation functions on the first dense layer (sigmoid, tanh, linear(!), relu), different learning rates, decays and number of epochs. But every time I have no fitting progress after first epoch (as example):

```
Epoch 1/10
72952/72952 [==============================] - 3s 42us/step - loss: 5.6170 - acc: 0.6515 - val_loss: 5.8685 - val_acc: 0.6359
Epoch 2/10
72952/72952 [==============================] - 2s 32us/step - loss: 4.9206 - acc: 0.6947 - val_loss: 5.8685 - val_acc: 0.6359
Epoch 3/10
72952/72952 [==============================] - 2s 33us/step - loss: 4.9206 - acc: 0.6947 - val_loss: 5.8685 - val_acc: 0.6359
Epoch 4/10
72952/72952 [==============================] - 2s 32us/step - loss: 4.9206 - acc: 0.6947 - val_loss: 5.8685 - val_acc: 0.6359
Epoch 5/10
72952/72952 [==============================] - 2s 33us/step - loss: 4.9206 - acc: 0.6947 - val_loss: 5.8685 - val_acc: 0.6359
```

I know that it is wrong behaviour, but I can't get what is the reason. Could you please help me to understand this problem?

Comment: Did you normalize your data? Your feature vector are too diverse and its hard for the model to converge. Take a look at this thread: https://medium.com/@lahorekid/a-dummies-guide-to-data-normalization-for-neural-nets-ff1998116e75

Comment: @AmirHadifar Thanks you! It works now and loss is going down and accuracy is increasing. I should read more about data preprocessing.

Comment: I am happy it fix your issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the issue was resolved by normalizing the input data as suggested by @AmirHadifar [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369544/model-not-converge-loss-not-decrease#comment91685458_52369544).

*Note: this answer is posted as community wiki as suggested in [accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/2099607) of ["Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251597/2099607).*